# Evaluate the sum of power series

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, power-series

> Evaluate $\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-\pi})\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k\pi}$

$$\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-\pi})\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k\pi}=\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-\pi}{})({{1+e^{-\pi}+e^{-2\pi}}+\cdots+e^{-n\pi}})=\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-\pi})\frac{1-e^{-(n+1)\pi}}{(1-e^{-\pi})}$$

I don't understand how can i get $\frac{1-e^{-(n+1)\pi}}{(1-e^{-\pi})}$,,
can i use $\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k\pi}= \frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(-k\pi)^n}{n!}$ ? Can someone give me some hint? Thank you!

Comment: remove $\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k\pi}= \frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{(-k\pi)^n}{n!}$ which is a non-sense. And can you evaluate $(1-e^{-\pi})\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-k\pi} = ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact
$$
\mathrm{e}^{ak} = \left(\mathrm{e}^a\right)^k = x^k
$$
Coupled with the geometric series.

Comment: hello thanks for answering my question, but why it is $\frac{a(1-r^{(n+1)}}{(1-r)}$ ?  if i want to make it  $\frac{a(1-r^{(n))}}{(1-r)}$ i should make the summation $\sum_{k=1}^n$ (?)

Comment: @fiksx Take a look here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html. You will see why the sum of the first $n$ terms has $n+1$ in there.

Comment: thankyou so much!! i got it!!